# How to move log4j.properties outside jar file?

Tags: java, gradle, log4j

I build a `jar` file with gradle, my app uses `log4j`. Initially my `log4j.properties` was embedded in my jar file. I moved it outside to be able to modify it in production. I updated the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file embedded in my jar file to reflect this:

```
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.1 lib/slf4j-api-1.4.2.jar
            lib/slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
            lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar
            ...
            lib/log4j.properties
```

My filetree is as follows on a windows7 32bit machine:

```
root/myapp.jar
root/lib/log4j.properties
```

I start my app with this command:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration='lib\log4j.properties' -Dlog4j.debug=true -jar myapp.jar > logs/output.log
```

my `logs/output.log` says that log4j could not find its property file:

```
log4j: Trying to find ['lib\log4j.properties'] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17fa65e.
log4j: Trying to find ['lib\log4j.properties'] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@17fa65e class loader.
log4j: Trying to find ['lib\log4j.properties'] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: ['lib\log4j.properties'].
```

I also tried with:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration='lib/log4j.properties'
-Dlog4j.configuration='log4j.properties'
-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

When I embed the file in the jar, it works:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18385e3.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/myapp/myapp.jar!/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/myapp/myapp-2.1.9.jar!/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[debug, A].
```

But I need it outside... Any idea?

Comment: Since a jar file is a just a zip archive, most compress/uncompress programs will let you edit text files inside the jar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:lib/log4j.properties
```

but i'm curious: does the Class-Path definition in the manifest really work? Jars, yes, that's standard, but does it work for log4j.properties, too?

Comment: `file:` prefix works. I don't know if Class-path definitions work for `log4j.properties`, that's my original question :-)

Comment: I've never tried the Class-Path route, tbh. The Oracle documentation on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html speaks only about JAR files in the Class-Path header. You'd want something like the lib directory in the classpath. I just tried it here with a dummy project, and couldn't get it to work.